# drop down list sorting values dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a drop list in gridview In which I am selecting a data in dropdown list from database like this

```
Adeel
Akram
Ali
Asif
Zeeshan
```

Problem is that when gridview loads for example with 5 rows for data inserting the data shows in drop down is sorted in such a way the on each row first element is adeel but I want to sort the names according row For Example In first row the element should show as adeel and in second row value should show as Akram and so on.Below is my code in which I am using to load griview for data inserting

```
For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    Dim ddlEmpCode As DropDownList = CType(gvRow.FindControl("DropDownlist1"), DropDownList)
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DatabaseConnectionString2").ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("insert into Status(m_date,emp_code) values (@m_Date,@EMp_Code)", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("m_Date", txtdate.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Animal_Code", ddlAnimalCode.SelectedValue)
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    Label1.Text = "All Records are Saved Successfully"
    btnInsert.Enabled = False
Next
```

Comment: Your problem and desired situation are exactly the same!? Please explain more...

Comment: Sir Normaly when dropdown shows then in each row of gridivew only the first element show but i want to show next element in next row

Comment: Sir If U got it then please answer or tell me i show with more details

Comment: Unfortunately i read whole text 4times and get nothing. When your program starts, do you have an empty grid view which is going to be filled? So what is the INSERT command in code? OR if your program starts and going to insert something what does exactly gridview do for you?

Comment: OK i got it. But your code in question illustrated an insertion part which is not your problem OR your question is: "whether you select a right items in dropdown lists, the first choice added in database"?

Comment: Sir I only shown my inserting code coz i want to insert the selected value also to database with existing context So the New Code Should be adjusted in my above code in question

Comment: So where r u now Give the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code..try to set the selected index of dropdown in rowdatabound event as follow...

```
protected void GridView1_RowDatabound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DropDownList drpdwnList = ((DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownlist1"));                   
                drpdwnList.SelectedIndex=e.Row.RowIndex;
            }
        }
```

**I have written this in C#,u need to write the same in Vb

Comment: Sir Error Showing in this line `drpdwnList.Items.SelectedIndex = e.Row.RowIndex` as `Selected Index is not a member of System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection` what should do for this ?